# Marginalization of conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian-network, marginal-distribution

I am working through [these examples of computations on Bayesian networks](http://cs.nyu.edu/faculty/davise/ai/bayesnet.html) and came across this claim (part of the last sample computation):

$$
P(E=e|A=a) = \sum_{c \in C} P(E=e, C=c | A=a)
$$

I am newly familiar with marginalization, but I thought that it was:

$$
P(A=a) = \sum_{b \in B} P(A=a,B=b) = \sum_{b \in B} P(A=a|B=b)P(B=b)
$$

If the first equation is true, can someone explain? I have tried searching for "marginalizing conditional probability" but have not found anything that seems similar.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By definition of conditional probability* we have that:

$$P(E=e|A=a)=\frac{P(E=e,A=a)}{P(A=a)}=\frac{\sum_{c}P(E=e,C=c,A=a)}{P(A=a)}$$

In the last step I used marginalization over $c$.
Then, again using the definition of conditional probability, this is equal to:

$$\sum_{c}P(E=e,C=c|A=a)$$.

*Definition of conditional probability:

$$P(x_1,...,x_n|y_1,...,y_m)=\frac{P(x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m)}{P(y_1,...,y_m)}$$

Answer (score 6):

Conditional probabilities are a *probability measure* meaning that they satisfy the axioms of probability, and enjoy all the properties of (unconditional) probability.

The practical use of this pontification is that *any* rule, theorem, or formula that you have learned about probabilities are also applicable if *everything* is assumed to be conditioned on the occurrence of some event. For example, knowing that $$P(B^c) = 1 - P(B)$$ allows us to immediately
conclude that $$P(B^c\mid A) = 1 - P(B\mid A)$$ is a valid result without going through writing out the formal definitions and completing a proof of the result.  So apply this idea to the formula
$$P(E) = \sum_i P(E \cap C_i)$$
where $C_1, C_2, \cdots $ is a *partition* of the sample space $\Omega$
into disjoint subsets (and so $(E \cap C_1)$, $(E \cap C_2), \cdots$ is a *partition* of $E$ into disjoint subsets). Conditioning everything on $A$ gives us 
$$P(E\mid A) = \sum_i P(E \cap C_i\mid A)$$
which is your formula in slightly different notation.