# Expand conditional by marginalisation and drop terms from conditional

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

I have come across this conditional expansion a few times, and I can't seem to make sense of it.

$$p(z|y) = \int{p(z|f)p(f|y)df}$$

I would go about it like this:

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
p(z|y) & = \frac{p(z,y)}{p(y)} \\
& = \frac{\int{p(z,f,y)df}}{p(y)} \\
& = \frac{\int{\cancel{p(y)}p(f|y)p(z|f,y)df}}{\cancel{p(y)}} \\
& = \int{p(z|f,\color{red}{y})p(f|y)df} \neq \int{p(z|f)p(f|y)df}
\end{align}

How is it that during the expansion we can drop the conditional on y from $p(z|f,y)$? I've seen it in a lot of papers on variational inference, and it's on the wikipedia page for [Bayesian Inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference#Bayesian_prediction): $\hspace{1em} p(\tilde{x}|X,\alpha) = \int{p(\tilde{x}|\theta)p(\theta|X,\alpha)d\theta}.\hspace{1em}$ Why isn't the first item in the integral $p(\tilde{x}|X,\alpha,\theta)$? I feel like I am missing some fundamental thing about conditioning which allows shuffling the conditionals around like this.

Similar to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/418295/marginalize-probability-with-three-variables) question, the conditioned on variable is present in all subsequent factors, why doesn't that happen in the above cases?

Comment: Yes, it is confusing.  My take on it is that since $z$ and $y$ are data, conditional upon $f$, $z$ and $y$ are assumed independent - in which case, $p(z|f,y) = p(z|f)$.  You don't want to build models $f$ such that there is still information in the observed data $y$ that is useful for helping to predict $z$ even knowing $f$, writing a little loosely, so we assume you don't.

Comment: @jbowman maybe you can convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @gunes - have done, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is confusing. However, there is some logic behind it.

Since $z$ and $y$ are data, conditional upon $f$, $z$ and $y$ are assumed independent - in which case, $p(z|f,y)=p(z|f)$. To make a concrete example, if you know that $z$ and $y$ are both distributed according to $f = \mathrm{Negative\ Binomial}(3, 0.7)$, $y$ contains no information about $z$ that you don't already have from knowing the distribution $f$; therefore, $p(z|f,y) = p(z|f)$.

As to whether you can achieve this happy ideal in practice - you don't want to build models $f$ such that there is still information in the observed data $y$ that is useful for helping to predict $z$ even knowing $f$, writing a little loosely, so we assume you don't.

Comment: This particular example comes from sparse Gaussian Processes, where $y$ is a noisy observation of the underlying $f$, and we are trying to learn the best inducing points $z$. Is this independence saying that $z$ is independent of $y$, as long as I condition on $f$, because the information of $y$ is contained in/mediated through $f$? Will most latent variable models break down like this?

Comment: There's nothing special, in this regard at any rate, about latent variable models.  The model is conditional upon the observed data, and the unobserved data distribution is conditional upon the model; integrating out the model makes the unobserved data distribution conditional upon the observed data.

Comment: Thanks, there is some serious probability-fu that I need to wrap my head around here!